# sql server 2012 service not running

Tags: sql-server, service, wmi, sql-server-2012

When starting my VM with windows server 2012 R2 which is my SQL-server, I get the following error:
[image]

My SQL-server service won't run if I start it or if it gets started automaticly.

What I have done so far:

- Ran *C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Binn\sqlservr.exe*, but there was nothing special in the errorlog.
- Tried to start the service in the SQL Server Configuration Manager. I couldn't even open the application. I got an error:
  [image]

  - To solve this error I ran the following command in the cmd:

`mofcomp "%programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Shared\sqlmgmproviderxpsp2up.mof"`

[image: desc]
[source](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-fix-sql-server-configuration-manager-cannot-connect-mohamed-fekry/)

[image: desc]

The error above is what I got when I tried starting the SQL-server service.
 The logfiles in *C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log* aren't that interesting. Except for the SQL Server Profiler log which is having red text:
[image]

I wonder what I could do next. The WMI service is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went to the system windows logs in the event viewer:
[image]

And I instantly knew what was wrong. I changed my password recently, because it expired. So I opened SQL Server Configuraton Manager and changed my password there as well:
[image]

Again I tried starting the SQL-server service in the server manager and this time it started.